# [Postgres][Python] -Why does printing print values in the database, but return does not? How to return a list of strings from database?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to manipulate a column in my database by turning it into a list of strings and then feeding it back to a function to grab more rows from the database. However, my function returns `<function c at 0x0000025473074598>` where as printing prints actual values in the database.

```
def c(x):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = NAME, user = USER, password = PASSWORD, host = HOST, port=PORT)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT * from course where cid ilike '{code}'"""
    new = sql.format(code=x)
    cur.execute(new)
    y = (cur.fetchone()) # I also tried fetchall()
    cur.close()
    print(y)
    #you = [list(i) for i in y]
    return y

if __name__=="__main__":
    c('CSC42184')
    print(c)

    ('CSC42184', 'BLAH', 'BLAH I want to manipulate this') #from the print statement in the function
    <function c at 0x0000randomnchar>
```

From the comment in the function, I have tried turning it into a list but it returns the same thing `<function c at 0x0000blahblah>`. **I want my function to return as a list of strings so I can index it for uses in other functions. How to do this?**

Comment: `result = c('CSC42184'); print(result)` you try to print object of the function `c` and get the output.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I missed this obvious answer. I don't think I can mark comments are correct(?) but yours is indeed correct.